# Trying to run UDP client server program in python involving a broker(the server), a producer(client) and a subscriber(client) with docker containers

Tags: python, server, network-programming, udp, client

When I run the containers and then run the corresponding python files in their terminals they don't communicate with each other like they are supposed to. I am confident that my docker networking is not the problem and that it is my code. If you can see any problems please let me know.

When I run the containers and then run the corresponding python files in their terminals they don't communicate with each other like they are supposed to. I am confident my docker networking is not the problem. I think it is somewhere in my code.

**server.py**

```
import socket
import struct

# Server configuration
server_host = "127.0.0.1"  # Listen on all available network interfaces
server_port = 12345
buffer_size = 1024

# Define the header format (4 bytes for packet type, 4 bytes for producer ID)
header_format = "4s4s"

# Create a UDP socket for receiving data from the producer
producer_receive_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
producer_receive_socket.bind((server_host, server_port))

# Create a UDP socket for sending requests to the producer
producer_send_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

print(f"Server is listening on {server_host}:{server_port}")

while True:
    try:
        # Receive a request from a subscriber
        request, subscriber_address = producer_receive_socket.recvfrom(buffer_size)
        header = struct.unpack(header_format, request[:8])

        packet_type = header[0].decode('utf-8')
        producer_id = header[1].decode('utf-8')

        if packet_type == "REQ":
            room_info = request[8:].decode('utf-8')

            # Simulate forwarding the request to the appropriate producer
            producer_address = "127.0.0.1"  # Replace with the actual producer's address
            producer_port = 12345  # Replace with the actual producer's port

            # Create a new header for the producer (packet type: REQ, producer ID)
            producer_header = struct.pack(header_format, b"REQ", producer_id.encode('utf-8'))

            # Send the request to the producer with the updated header
            producer_request = producer_header + room_info.encode('utf-8')
            producer_send_socket.sendto(producer_request, (producer_address, producer_port))

            # Receive the response from the producer
            producer_response, _ = producer_receive_socket.recvfrom(buffer_size)

            # Forward the producer's response to the subscriber
            producer_send_socket.sendto(producer_response, subscriber_address)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Server shutting down...")
        producer_receive_socket.close()
        producer_send_socket.close()
        break
```

**producer.py**

```
import socket
import struct

# Producer configuration
producer_id = "PRODUCER1"
server_host = "127.0.0.1"  # Replace with your broker's hostname or IP address
server_port = 12345
buffer_size = 1024

# Define the header format (4 bytes for packet type, 4 bytes for producer ID)
header_format = "4s4s"

# Create a UDP socket for the producer
producer_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
producer_socket.bind(("localhost", server_port))  # Bind to the specified port

print(f"Producer {producer_id} is listening for subscriber requests on port {server_port}")

while True:
    try:
        # Wait for a request from the subscriber
        request, _ = producer_socket.recvfrom(buffer_size)

        # Unpack the header
        header = struct.unpack(header_format, request[:8])
        packet_type = header[0].decode('utf-8')
        producer_id = header[1].decode('utf-8')

        if packet_type == "REQ":
            room_info = request[8:].decode('utf-8')

            # Simulate temperature and humidity data for two rooms
            room_data = {
                "room1-temperature": 25.5,
                "room1-humidity": 50.0,
                "room2-temperature": 22.0,
                "room2-humidity": 60.0,
            }

            if room_info in room_data:
                data_to_send = struct.pack(header_format, b"RES", producer_id.encode('utf-8'))
                data_to_send += f"{room_data[room_info]:.2f}".encode('utf-8')

                # Send the requested data to the subscriber
                producer_socket.sendto(data_to_send, (server_host, server_port))
                print(f"Producer {producer_id}: Sent data for {room_info}")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Producer shutting down...")
        producer_socket.close()
        break
```

**subscriber.py**

```
import socket
import struct

# Subscriber configuration
subscriber_id = "SUBSCRIBER1"
server_host = "127.0.0.1"  # Replace with your broker's hostname or IP address
server_port = 12345
buffer_size = 1024

# Define the header format (4 bytes for packet type, 4 bytes for producer ID)
header_format = "4s4s"

# Create a UDP socket for the subscriber
subscriber_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    try:
        # Prompt the user to choose a room
        room_choice = input("Choose a room (room1 or room2): ")
        if room_choice not in ["room1", "room2"]:
            print("Invalid room choice. Please choose room1 or room2.")
            continue

        # Create the header (packet type: REQ, producer ID: SUB1)
        header = struct.pack(header_format, b"REQ", subscriber_id.encode('utf-8'))

        # Send a request to the server with the header and room choice
        request_data = header + room_choice.encode('utf-8')
        subscriber_socket.sendto(request_data, (server_host, server_port))
        print(f"Subscriber {subscriber_id}: Sent request for data in {room_choice}")

        # Receive and unpack the response from the server
        response, _ = subscriber_socket.recvfrom(buffer_size)
        header = struct.unpack(header_format, response[:8])
        packet_type = header[0].decode('utf-8')
        producer_id = header[1].decode('utf-8')

        if packet_type == "RES" and producer_id == "PRODUCER1":
            data = response[8:].decode('utf-8')
            print(f"Subscriber {subscriber_id}: Received data for {room_choice} - {data}")
            break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Subscriber shutting down...")
        subscriber_socket.close()
        break
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).